# Magento 2 - Exclude block from fpc without ajax

Tags: magento2

I want to insert custom block on PDP.

I can use `cacheable="false"` for this block or mark it as `_isScopePrivate"`. But in the first solutions the whole page will not be cached.

Drawback of the second solutions is this block will be downloaded via ajax. But it's noticeable on the page. I can see first the old content then new one loaded.

Can I exclude block from fpc without ajax? Something like magento 1 implements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it because page can cache in Varnish and only one way to add block to cached page is ESI

Comment: how to use ESI?

Comment: set ttl="time" attribute to block in layout

Comment: to un cache, i have to set ttl time to 0 right ?